# Visualforce Remoting and Relationships

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

**Question**

Is it possible to leverage relationships with Visualforce remoting, including one object as a property of another?

**Background**

I've been playing around but always seem to get a VF remoting exception in the console with no useful information:

```
> Visualforce Remoting Exception:  VFRemote.js:118 $VFRM.Util.error
> VFRemote.js:118 (anonymous function) VFRemote.js:133 a.Event.fire
> VFRemote.js:52 a.Observable.fireEvent VFRemote.js:47
> _Visualforce.Direct._Visualforce.extend.onProviderData VFRemote.js:87 a.Event.fire VFRemote.js:52 a.Observable.fireEvent VFRemote.js:47
> _Visualforce.direct.RemotingProvider._Visualforce.extend.onData VFRemote.js:95
> _Visualforce.extend.handleResponse VFRemote.js:76 a VFRemote.js:39 (anonymous function)
```

I'm assuming that it's just not supported and I'm making the type-conversion routines throw a bit of a hissy fit, but it'd be good to know if it's just me doing something stupid.

**Rough Code Example**

If i Had ObjectA_*c and ObjectB*_c, where A has a lookup to B, is there a way to pass an instance of ObjectA_*c to a remote method with an instance of ObjectB*_c going along for the ride?

**In the page**

```
function ObjectA__c()
{
  this.Name = '';
  this.ObjB__r = null;              
}

function ObjectB__c()
{
  this.Name = '';
}

**snip**

var b = new ObjectB__c();
b.Name = 'New B';

var a = new ObjectA__c();
a.Name = 'New A';
a.ObjB__r = b;

Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
  '{!$RemoteAction.TheController.UpsertA}',
  a,
  function(result, event) {
    console.log(result);
  }
);
```

**In the controller**

```
global static void UpsertA(ObjectA__c objA)
{
  upsert objA.ObjB__r;
  upsert objA;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, although I'm not sure what the error message is that you are seeing.

I see an issue in the controller code.  The Id reference field needs to be assigned after the first upsert is done.

```
global static void UpsertA(ObjectA__c objA)
{
  upsert objA.ObjB__r;
  // Add this line
  objA.ObjB__c = objA.ObjB__r.Id;
  upsert objA;
}
```

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/peterknolle/4761339) I put together with stripped down code that has it working.